# Is it possible to make Map<?, ?> someMethod work with JAX-B?

Tags: jaxb, cxf

When trying to generate web service artifacts using `cxf-java2ws-plugin`, which in turn uses JAX-B, I get the error below on a method that looks like this:

```
  Map<?, ?> myMethod(...);
```

Changing the method signature is a last resort so i'm looking for alternatives.

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Map is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at java.util.Map
                at private java.util.Map com.company.SomeClass.arg2
                at com.company.SomeClass
java.util.Map does not have a no-arg default constructor.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at java.util.Map
                at private java.util.Map
```

Answer (score 1):

JAXB will allow you to have a property of type `Map`, but not to use it as a root level object.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/jaxb-and-javautilmap.html